# Simple Random Walk question

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes, random-walk

I am having trouble with these questions, I understand the rules I am meant to use, such as Markov property and independent increments yet I am having issues applying that to the question. I am also fully aware that *Xn = Z1 +· · ·+Zn for some iid variables Zn with P(Zn = 1) = 1−P(Zn = −1) =1/4.*

I actually have the solutions however I still don't understand how the answer was derived, especially question 2 and question 3 of exercise 1

Let {Xn} be a simple random walk with the probability of an upward move given
by 1/4. Calculate:

**Q1) P(X2 = 2)**

**Q2) P(X2 = 0, X4 = 2)**

**Q3) P(X2 = 1, X4 = 2)**

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Given that you already have the answers and are having trouble understanding how to derive them, it may be useful to enumerate all possible combinations of states $(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4)$ and the chance of each occurring.

````
library(dplyr)

four_states <- expand.grid(Z_1 = c(-1, 1),
                           Z_2 = c(-1, 1),
                           Z_3 = c(-1, 1),
                           Z_4 = c(-1, 1),
                           KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(X_1 = Z_1,
         X_2 = Z_1 + Z_2,
         X_3 = Z_1 + Z_2 + Z_3,
         X_4 = Z_1 + Z_2 + Z_3 + Z_4) %>%
  mutate(P_Z_1 = 1/4 * (Z_1 == 1) + 3/4 * (Z_1 == -1),
         P_Z_2 = 1/4 * (Z_2 == 1) + 3/4 * (Z_2 == -1),
         P_Z_3 = 1/4 * (Z_3 == 1) + 3/4 * (Z_3 == -1),
         P_Z_4 = 1/4 * (Z_4 == 1) + 3/4 * (Z_4 == -1)) %>%
  mutate(P = P_Z_1 * P_Z_2 * P_Z_3 * P_Z_4)

# Q1) P(X2 = 2)
four_states %>%
  filter(X_2 == 2) %>%
  summarise(ans = sum(P))

# Q2) P(X2 = 0, X4 = 2)
four_states %>%
  filter(X_2 == 0, X_4 == 2) %>%
  summarise(ans = sum(P))

# Q3) P(X2 = 1, X_4 = 2)
four_states %>%
  filter(X_2 == 1, X_4 == 2) %>%
  summarise(ans = sum(P))
```
````

Comment: wow thank  you very much